# How to limit a certain transaction code for a certain user [ABAP Programming]

Tags: abap

i just wanted to know how do you limit a certain user in SAP NetWeaver Developers Kit for using a custom transaction code.

am accessing this code "se80" wherein we can create our own program to customize the SAP system, however my case is that I want it to limit.

For example the General Manager can use this custom transaction code eg(ZBDGEN) wherein he/she can use the custom program/transaction code, while the Sales Clerk can only use the custom program/transaction code eg(ZBDSC)

I created a two program the 1st program was to update/edit/delete privilege used by General Manager, while the 2nd program is a copy of the 1st program but the program can only used for update and used by the Sales Clerk.

And I think it is more better if the transaction code is limited for a certain user, for privilege purposes and security purposes.

Comment: What is "SAP NetWeaver Developers Kit"?

Answer (score 4):

By assigning tcodes to roles and assign those roles to particular users, you can achieve what you need. Directly you can't give authorization to Tcodes for users. More than that, you wont have access to assign roles and all. Only your Basis team has authorization to do this.

The Tcodes involved in these activities are **PFCG** and **SU01**.

Comment: Some companies have separate Security teams, in which case you should work with them instead of the Basis team.